# Can not get the js file in using requirejs

Tags: javascript, nginx, requirejs

I'm trying to build client project using requireJs.
But when I published it on the nginx server, an error occurred.
[This is my project directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fagf.png)

when it ran here, the browser threw a js error.

```
require(['config/require.conf'], function(){
    'use strict';
    require(['src/common/js/pageloader'], function(pageloader){
        pageloader();
    })
})
```

js error:

`GET http://localhost:8011/src/homepage/config/require.conf.js  require.js:1961`

It seems like the error occurred because I use the relative path (lack of '/').

However, I add the slash as prefix of directory('/config/require.conf').
As a result, when the browser ran here, requirejs didn't add the suffix ".js" for the js file(config/require.conf.js).

Another error occurred~

```
 GET http://localhost:8011/config/require.conf 404 (Not Found)
```

What should I do for the error? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the correct `baseUrl:` configuration for requireJS.
I faced similar issues while working with DOJO which has require.

Comment: @KRISHNAPATEL hello, thanks for your answer. But the baseUrl is also in the require.conf. We can't find the configuration file of requirejs.

Comment: Then I guess you need to include the configuration in html using `<script>` tag because before you start using `require` you need to have the configuration ready. or try
`require(['../../config/require.conf'], function(){
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass two things in the dependency list of a `require` call:

- A module name. This is the default. When you pass a module name, RequireJS will convert the name to a path using `baseUrl`, `paths`, `map`, etc. from your RequireJS configuration.
- A path. RequireJS considers that you are passing a path if the dependency: a) begins with '/', (which is your case), b) contains an HTML query (e.g. 'foo?bar=1'), c) ends with the `.js` extension, d) specifies a protocol (e.g. `https://`).

  **In this case, RequireJS uses the path as-is, without using its configuration to transform it, and it does not automatically add a `.js` extension to it.**

Your usage is the 2nd case so you have to add `.js` to your path so that RequireJS can find your file:

```
require(['/config/require.conf.js'], function() {
```